# Facebook mobile phone activation

Tags: censorship, verification

Why does the hidden service of facebook (http://facebookcorewwwi.onion) ask for a mobile phone verification? Isn't the goal of TOR to be able to visit pages which are censored in some countries (e.g. from China) **anonymously**? This does not make sense to me.

Comment: This actually doesn't have anything to do with Tor. That's just how Facebook decided to program their website and onion service.

Comment: I know it does not. But I did not know where to post this. Meta would have been the SE platform I would have posted it, but I had too few reputation for doing so.

Answer (score 4):

[Facebook allows neither anonymous nor pseudonymous accounts](https://www.facebook.com/help/112146705538576). That means you can't sign into Facebook as a guest, nor can you use a name that isn't your real name. It then follows that when you visit Facebook, either on the clearnet or via Tor, you have to sign in with your own credentials.

If you're signing in with your own credentials, then Facebook has to check it's actually you, and not someone breaking into your account. (I'm sure you'll agree that this check is a Good Thing.)

If you're using the Facebook hidden service (i.e. .onion site) via the Tor Browser, then Facebook is unable to validate you in the way it normally would (e.g. using cookies, your location implied by your IP address, etc.), and so requires another method, in this case via your phone.

Answer (score 1):

Tor is *just a transport layer*. It helps you to avoid illegal censorship attempts. It's defenately **not an anonymizer** - and even  more, phone activation is good for privacy protection

Comment: Many users use Tor to anonymize themselves. For example: Let's say a Chinese person posts negative stuff about the Chinese government on Facebook, how would he make sure the government won't punish him? He can't use a pseudonym in Facebook. If he would, he would fail the test (many users need to send Facebook their id when not having a phone number). What sense does this make?

Comment: @Benni it's not for anonymity for sure - but to ensure you that even in a censorship case you can use Facebook. And - as far as I know - some pseudonym cases are OK on Facebook

Comment: @Alecey Vesnin well, some of them are. But most of them are not allowed. How would I post things about my country I'm not allowed to withouth being able to use a fake name?
And if I would provide a phone number instead of my id in China for example, Facebook would text me - And the government would know that I'm using Facebook even though it's forbidden.

Comment: @Benni who said that you must provide your number? or a number in your country? who says? ;)

Comment: [Facebook](http://imgur.com/VcEIVIA) ;)

Comment: @Benni it asks a *phone number*. If you're so concerned about your privacy - buy one not in your country =) Start [here](http://www.anveo.com/mainphonenumbers.asp)

Comment: Wouldn't that 1. make the whole verification step useless and 2. destroy the concept of "free" use of Facebook?

Comment: @Benni the fee in this case will be not for using Facebook, but for avoiding your rights breaking. This number would be fine for many things binded to phone

Comment: Many users don't have the money/possibility to use online phone number. I don't think, such a big company as Facebook should rely on extern services like mobile numbers.

Comment: @Benni even a Facebook **can't afford** it's own fully-personalized planet-wide authentication infrastructure, so the cell operators are not super-good, but defenatelu better than nothing

Comment: They don't need a planet-wide authentication infrastructure in my opinion... :)