# When logging into Facebook with Tor: "Your computer needs to be cleaned"

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, security

Can't log into Facebook using Tor. They want to install software to 'clean' your computer. I've run 3 different malware programs of my own, 
plus, I logged into Facebook using another browser and account name. So it's not my computer.
Firefox is the default browser for Tor. Is it possible to use another browser with Tor installed?

I tried to register here with my Facebook account, but I get the same error notice.
Thank you!
[image]

Comment: Facebook apparentñy has decided to flag accounts that use tor to connect. It is not your browser, it is not your device.I have tried with: a macbook pro, an android device, Fedora, Ubuntu, and even a windows surface that I have available at work, with and without TOR in all those devices. Exact same message, it makes you download an encumbered .exe file to run in your computer otherwise you are locked out of the service.
You know how this goes, contact Facebook's support team, who will ask for your driver's licence or passport so they can classify you appropiately and continue to use their mon

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I've been using TOR to access Facebook for sometime now with no problems. This prompt came up one time a month or so ago. I changed my identity, and I got in fine. This time it still blocks every time I change my identity.
I tried the .onion address, still get the prompt.
The 'virus' scannner it wants to install is [ESET Online Scanner](https://www.eset.com/us/online-scanner/). Instead of letting them install it, I did it on my own.
Result: 0 infected files.
More and more, a Facebook account is turning into an official form of identity, like a social security number or

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**
It's possible to use any TCP-based application that supports SOCKS proxying through Tor. **That doesn't mean you should.**

It's [not possible](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/52/how-can-i-use-chrome-through-tor-on-os-x) to use a different browser with Tor. The Tor Browser is a heavily modified version of Firefox that has a number of security enhancements that ensure all browser traffic is routed through the Tor network.

I was able to log into my Facebook account via Tor without any problems. I had to [verify my account via my phone](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/10275/1730), which is an acceptable security check, in my opinion. I was also able to access the mobile site, thereby bypassing the need to turn on Javascript. I have no suggestion as to why your case would be different - others may have a better idea.

One possible solution would be to use Facebook's Tor Hidden Service directly, rather than using the clearnet site. The fact that Facebook *have* an official .onion site shows at least some intent on supporting the Tor network and its users.

https://facebookcorewwwi.onion/

(Here's an official Tor blog entry from when Facebook enabled this service: https://blog.torproject.org/blog/facebook-hidden-services-and-https-certs)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it **is possible** to use any browser, that supports SOCKS and/or HTTP/HTTPS proxies with Tor : the browser **alone** will not protect your privacy - any browser can run a plugin or an XML-HTTP-REQUEST or similar stuff to leak out data. So - your problem is that an Exit node you're using is blacklisted by it's IP. change a tor circuit in *any* way suitable to you : tor button, telnet controllers, e.t.c... but the Facebook has an onion entry address, [officially maintained](https://www.facebook.com/notes/protect-the-graph/making-connections-to-facebook-more-secure/1526085754298237/) at https://facebookcorewwwi.onion